# How do I handle database.yml development mode configuration with multiple develpers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

what's the standard way of dealing with development mode database config for database.yml when there are multiple developers on a project?

Should all devs have the same database setup? Is that a smart requirement?

Or should there be some type of gitignore and symlinking taking place? I did this and after branching, the database.yml disappeared :(

I've also come up with an erb solution that seems to work well enough, but not sure if there will be unintended consequences. The following will allow devs to sed environment variables in their bash_profile in case they have a different local setup than the default. This will allow our database.yml file to stay in git.

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: <%= ENV['DEV_DB_DATABASE'] || 'app_development' %> 
  username: <%= ENV['DEV_DB_USERNAME'] || 'postgres' %>
  password: <%= ENV['DEV_DB_PASSWORD'] || '' %>
  host: localhost
  encoding: UTF8
```

Comment: I always share the same database.yml with other devs

Answer (score 2):

Add `database.yml.sample` file to the rails app, also add `database.yml` to the `.gitignore`. This way all developers can have different database setups.

Comment: please see my comment about this option causing issues on branching. I lost my database.yml file periodically.